# Jenkins for C++ Project with Docker

Tags: c++, docker, jenkins

I want to integrate my C++ project with Jenkins using Docker.
First I created a setup for Jenkins using:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git && apt-get install make g++ -y
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
ENV CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG /var/jenkins_home/casc.yaml
ENV JENKINS_ADMIN_ID=admin
ENV JENKINS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli -f /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
COPY casc.yaml /var/jenkins_home/casc.yaml
```

**plugins.txt**

```
ant:latest
antisamy-markup-formatter:latest
authorize-project:latest
build-timeout:latest
cloudbees-folder:latest
configuration-as-code:latest
credentials-binding:latest
email-ext:latest
git:latest
github-branch-source:latest
gradle:latest
ldap:latest
mailer:latest
matrix-auth:latest
pam-auth:latest
pipeline-github-lib:latest
pipeline-stage-view:latest
ssh-slaves:latest
timestamper:latest
workflow-aggregator:latest
ws-cleanup:latest
```

**casc.yaml**

```
jenkins:
  securityRealm:
    local:
      allowsSignup: false
      users:
       - id: ${JENKINS_ADMIN_ID}
         password: ${JENKINS_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
  authorizationStrategy:
    globalMatrix:
      permissions:
        - "USER:Overall/Administer:admin"
        - "GROUP:Overall/Read:authenticated"
  remotingSecurity:
      enabled: true
security:
  queueItemAuthenticator:
    authenticators:
    - global:
        strategy: triggeringUsersAuthorizationStrategy
unclassified:
  location:
    url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

So far, so good. I used `docker build -t jenkins:jcasc .` and `docker run --name jenkins --rm -p 8080:8080 jenkins:jcasc` and **Jenkins starts normally**. I entered the user name (admin) and the password and it worked.

**There are although 2 issues that Jenkins displays:**

**-> It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken.**

**-> Building on the built-in node can be a security issue. You should set up distributed builds. See the documentation.**

I ignored them so far, and continued with my project and **installed Blue Ocean.**
After installing Blue Ocean I connected it to my GitHub repository and for this I created a token and the pipeline was created, but it is not giving any result.

***The log says:***

```
Branch indexing

Connecting to https://api.github.com with no credentials, anonymous access

Jenkins-Imposed API Limiter: Current quota for Github API usage has 37 remaining (1 over budget). Next quota of 60 in 36 min. Sleeping for 4 min 43 sec.

Jenkins is attempting to evenly distribute GitHub API requests. To configure a different rate limiting strategy, such as having Jenkins restrict GitHub API requests only when near or above the GitHub rate limit, go to "GitHub API usage" under "Configure System" in the Jenkins settings.
```

****My C++ project looks like this:****

```
-->HelloWorld
  |
  -->HelloWorld.cpp
-->scripts
  |
  -->Linux-Build.sh
  |
  -->Linux-Run.sh
-->Jenkinsfile
```

**HelloWorld.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Linux-Build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

vendor/bin/premake/premake5 gmake2
make
```

**Linux-Run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

bin/Debug/HelloWorld
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Building..."'
                sh 'chmod +x scripts/Linux-Build.sh'
                sh 'scripts/Linux-Build.sh'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'bin/Debug/*', fingerprint: true
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Running..."'
                sh 'chmod +x scripts/Linux-Run.sh'
                sh 'scripts/Linux-Run.sh'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, where might be the problem? I don't know if the problem is in my C++ code, or in the Docker configuration.
I am also a big fan of cmake, instead of make and I would prefer to use cmake for this, but I am not sure how to integrate this and make it work.

**EDIT:**
***In the tutorial that I followed there was a "vendor" directory but the instructor didn't show what was in that directory.***

**EDIT:**
The program took 4 minutes but it eventually did something and the error is:

```
+ scripts/Linux-Build.sh

scripts/Linux-Build.sh: line 3: vendor/bin/premake/premake5: No such file or directory

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

script returned exit code 2
```

So, the problem is in the C++ project, not Docker.